# Akka-http: How do I map response to object

Tags: scala, akka-http

Not sure if I'm getting this whole routing DSL thing right but here's the question. I want to do a post to external service such as:

```
val post = pathPrefix("somePath") {
  post {     
    //get the response mapped to my Output object
  }
}
```

Then I want the response (which is a Json) to be mapped to an object matching the fields for example Output (assuming I have my JsonProtocol set up). How is this done?

Comment: To make a call to an external service, use the [client API](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/index.html). The Routing DSL is part of the server-side API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using HTTP server directives to "retrieve" something "externally". This is what typically an HTTP client does.

For this sort of things, you can use [akka http client api](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/index.html).

For example:

```
val response = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://akka.io"))
response onComplete { 
  case Success(res) =>
    val entity = Unmarshal(res.entity).to[YourDomainObject]
    // use entity here
  case Failure(ex) =>  // do something here 
}
```

However, this requires some [Unmarshaller](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/unmarshalling.html) (to deserialize the received json). Take also a look at [Json Support](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html), as it helps you define marshallers easily:

```
case class YourDomainObject(id: String, name: String)
implicit val YourDomainObjectFormat = jsonFormat2(YourDomainObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to ask is how to get the body i.e in JSOn format to the Case class that you have

Here is a quick example:

```
    path("createBot" / Segment) { tag: String =>
            post {
              decodeRequest {
                entity(as[CaseClassName]) { caseclassInstance: CaseClassName =>
                   val updatedAnswer = doSomeStuff(caseclassInstance)
                  complete {
                    "Done"
                  }
                }
          }
```

You can find more detailed example from here : https://github.com/InternityFoundation/Stackoverflowbots/blob/master/src/main/scala/in/internity/http/RestService.scala#L56

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: I know that part. I'm asking how to map the response coming from external service. Something like:

  val out = complete{ response => Unmarshal(response).to[Output]} if that makes sense.